# Layout two text views

Tags: android, layout

I have to put two text views in one line. Second one should be placed next to first one (as shown in figure 1).

My problem is: text of first text view may be long so I need to ellipsize it. It should take as much space as needed to make it possible to read the whole text in second text view. Figure 2 shows it.

Is it possible to achieve that using Android built-in layours or I need to write my custom view?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Create an inner layout and use the `android:weightSum="100"` attribute. Then place two text views insode this inner layout and add the attribute `android:layout_weight="50"` to each textview!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="A long long text" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="A long text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Regards

Comment: Hello. It worked almost as expected (I achieved same result using Relative layout). When first text view string is short (eg. "test") second text view is placed at right of its parent (here: linear layout). But in this case, I want both of them to be aligned to the left.